# How to get last date of posting date for a material in particular movement in power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have to select last date pick happened for material. My example as shown.
For material 1488341 for pick type ,last pick happened on 26-07-2021.
i used formula:

Table Name=details

```
Last Pick = 

VAR  CurrentMat = details[Material Number]

return

    MAXX(FILTER(ALL(details),details[Material Number]=CurrentMat && details[Type]='Pick')
        details[Date]).
```

But it is not working.

[image: picture]

Answer (score 0):

Use this calculation:

```
MaxPickDate = calclulate(MAX(details[Date]), FILTER(ALL(details), details[Material Number] = SELECTEDVALUE([Material Number]) &&  details[Type]='Pick'))
```

We need here SELECTEDVALUE([Material Number]), to know what Numer to check (current row Material Number);